# Does JMESPath have an 'in' like operator, that will be true if a key's value is present in an array of strings?

Tags: ansible, jmespath, json-query

Does JMESPath have an 'in' like operator, that will be true if a key's value is present in an array of strings?

Given the following snippet of data, (assume the number of items is much larger, and I want to select a few)

```json
[
  {
    "object": {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "item1"
      }
    },
    "data": {}
  },
  {
    "object": {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "item2"
      }
    },
    "data": {}
  },
  {
    "object": {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "item3"
      }
    },
    "data": {}
  }
]
```

Is there something that would allow me to select any object, whose metadata.name key's value is in the list ['item1', 'item2']?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: ***"Select any object, whose metadata.name key's value is in the list ['item1', 'item2']"***

A: Use the [JmesPath](https://jmespath.org/) built-in function [contains](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains). The below query does what you want

```bash
[?contains(['item1', 'item2'], object.metadata.name)]
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    data:
      - data: {}
        object:
          metadata:
            name: item1
      - data: {}
        object:
          metadata:
            name: item2
      - data: {}
        object:
          metadata:
            name: item3

    result: "{{ data|json_query(result_query) }}"
    result_query: |
      [?contains(['item1', 'item2'], object.metadata.name)]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  result:
  - data: {}
    object:
      metadata:
        name: item1
  - data: {}
    object:
      metadata:
        name: item2
```

- You can put the list into a variable. For example,

```yaml
    result: "{{ data|json_query(result_query) }}"
    filter: ['item1', 'item2']
    result_query: |
      [?contains({{ filter }}, object.metadata.name)]
```